# Is Using a Static Configuration Class Good Practice?

Tags: java, android

In my project I am developing at the moment, I have many configuration settings. Things such as

- Alarm times
- Amount of items to retrieve from the server
- LocationManager integers such as minium location

These are all static final and are all in a class that corresponds to the value.

My question is, are there any problems with moving all of these values to a single static class?

My thinking is that when it comes to testing and tweeking the app, it will be easier to manage.

Comment: I would if possible externalize the config so you can change it at run time without rebuilding.

Comment: Your question is fuzzy. Are you talking about a file or static constants in a class / interface ?

Comment: I think its clear, the questions says that they are in a class and asks, should I move them to another class

Comment: The text of the quesiton is clear, but doesn't match the title.  A better title might be Is a singleton class for static configuration constants good practice?

Comment: Very true, I don't know why I wrote that title I will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @Snicolas's answer...

You should indeed persist your CONFIGURATION settings outside of code (file or database).  BUT you should not "read" that configuration each time a value is required, that would be inefficient.

Using a class to manage configuration (ie. AppSettings) is a good idea.  Making it static is one way to provide singleton-like access.  In C# and ASP.NET a web app will guarantee one and only one instance of a static class and therefore multiple un-related requests from different users will share the exact same static values.

But in your case (I see the tag 'android') using Java your best bet may be a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) approach.  I don't know how garbage collection works in Java but I'd say you should use a singleton to ensure one-and-only-one instance of your settings.  The singleton Ensures an instance exists (or creates one if not) and then provides it to the caller.

This may also make it easier to support the ability to change configuration values while the app is running -- you can "watch" for setting changes on a regular basis.

I'm not a Java man but I'd be surprised (well no not really) if there wasn't already a library for handling this very problem.

Comment: ... and before the haters start knocking the C# ASP.NET static class concept, YES, I am aware of potential race conditions and other not-thread-safe issues with this approach.

Comment: Actually a static class with all the configurations loaded in a static block will do the job without any threading issues or problems. It will also make sure that configurations are only loaded during the application deployment. There will be no need to make it a singleton since everything is static. If you want to change the configs while app is running you will be better off with some database take for the configs with a cache being refreshed at a set interval.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are not talking about constants as you mentionned alarm times.

The problem with using only static fields inside a dedicated class is that your class can be garbage collected if the device is under memory pressure. In that case, they would simply be lost and reset when you would use them again.

So you should really consider persisting them in a file or in a database depending on the amount of data you wanna store. SharedPreferences can be usefull for a small amount of data, otherwise, consider using a database. That's a much more scalable solution and access times are better for larger data sets.

Comment: You can set repeating alarms. I pass 1 hour(in millisecond) to the alarm manager for instance

Answer (score 0):

In the Rails world, it's good practice to implement a configuration model class that lazily loads and caches configuration information, which is persistently stored in serialized form in a simple two-column (key and serial data value) table or (less often) a flat file.  A configuration editor is then just a View for this model.

This ought to be a good solution in Android as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea will be to store these constants in a `properties` file. And load the constants when you need them. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/loading-java-properties-files/

Answer (score -2):

If you find it convenient, it's a good practice.